# Whenever i enter into terminal to open python, Command 'python' not found, did you mean: command 'python3' from deb python3

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, python, python3

I've installed ubuntu 20.04.3 lts, and I installed anaconda3 twice, first time from user privilege and once again from root privilege since not being activated conda. when i reopened the terminal, i need to type the command to be activated conda. But If i type '$whereis conda', it doesn't show the bin directory where it was actually installed. I typed like given below,

```
hilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$ python

Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3

thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$ whereis conda

conda: /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/condabin/conda

thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$ source /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/bin/activate

(base) thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$ conda init

no change     /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /home/thilipkumar/.bashrc
No action taken.

(base) thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$ source ~/.bashrc 

thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$ conda config --set auto_activate_base False

thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$ python

Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 19:58:26) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()

thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$
```

And i need to follow the same thing in root privilege too. If once i close and reopen the terminal, i need to do the same thing. Can anyone tell me a suggestion to solve this problem?   And last few lines of $vi .bashrc

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

And `echo $PATH` before activated

```
thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$ echo $PATH
/home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$
```

Comment: It is quite confusing, and I could not make out what the issue is. Please edit to add the summary of the problem.

Comment: You asked a very similar question yesterday. It's unclear to me how this question is different.

Comment: Should i activate anaconda3 every time i open the terminal by typing these commands? like $ source /home/thilipkumar/anaconda3/bin/activate

(base) thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$ conda init      (base) thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$ source ~/.bashrc

thilipkumar@thilipkumar-Inspiron-5520:~$ conda config --set auto_activate_base False       @user535733

Answer (score 1):

Your system reacts perfectly normal when you type `python`. **There is no executable python on a default Ubuntu install.**

On a default new install of Ubuntu 20.04, [`python` is not present](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Python3_by_default). So it is quite expected then that the command is not found. You can, however, install a command `python` that redirects to `python3` or one that redirects to Python 2.7, in which case Python 2 will be installed - it does not come by default on Ubuntu 20.04.

You can make your `python` command available by installing one of the `python-is*` packages:

sudo apt install python-is-python3

will install a symbolic link `/usr/bin/python` that links to `python3` in the same folder.

There is probably no need for you to do that since you are using anaconda. That is a tool that allows to use different python versions on the same system for developping and testing. It is of course very fine to use that, **but do in no way tamper with the system installed python3**. A linux desktop heavily relies on its system default python. Tampering with it will most likely break your system.

**Do not play with anaconda or with any other user application as root**. This is never needed, unless you like adventure and do not mind breaking your system now and then.